# How to use DefinitelyTyped types on forked packages?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

For packages that don't come with it's own types, next step is to look for `@types/<package>` for the package typings. However, if there is a package `X`, which is forked to a package `Y`. How can we use the same `@types/<X>` package for the package `Y`?

Edit:

Example: node-bunyan doesn't have types. @types/bunyan exists and provides types. Now,  I am trying to use a fork of node-bunyan(@scoop/bunyan) while still being able to utilize types from @types/bunyan.

Answer (score 5):

### Update:

By looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296731/how-can-i-install-typescript-declarations-for-scoped-namespaced-packages-via-ty) and [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/987a09b4979415a83491328a57cf4def5b7e1bc7#what-about-scoped-packages).

Probably you can add in your `tsconfig.json`

```json
   "paths":{
      "@scoop/bunyan": ["./node_modules/@types/bunyan"]
    }
```

---

Maybe you can add you to the package `Y` in `package.json` the path to `@types/<X>`.

```json
{
    ...
    "types": "./node_modules/@types/<X>/lib/main.d.ts",
    ...
}
```

Comment: This needs me to change the fork's package.json. Also, @types is mostly pluggable. Adding types to repos that don't have types without changing their package.json which is what I am looking for as well. 

Example: node-bunyan doesn't have types. @types/bunyan exists and provides types. Now,  I am trying to use a fork of node-bunyan while still being able to utilize types from @types/bunyan. 

Of course, it simply might not be possible to do it at all. Your solution probably would be a workaround in that case. Thanks!

Comment: @Querious I updated the answer with a possible solution!

Comment: @strdr4605 In the second solution, do I also have to add `@types/<X>` to the package's `package.json`? I can't get either solution to work. :(

Comment: I got the second solution to work in the end. As I suspected, I had to add the `@types/<X>` package. I then had a typo in the `"types"` path (triple check it!).

Answer (score 1):

You could pretend to NPM that the DT types have a different package name which matches your fork.

`npm i -D @types/scoop__bunyan@npm:@types/node-bunyan`

(This did the job for me just now -- I was suggested this idea by Gerrit0 on the Typescript Discord.)